# Dual Booted Ubuntu 22.04 not connecting to Wifi, same password works in Windows 11

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, 22.04, password

I have a Dell G15 AMD Ryzen Edition Laptop with Radeon Graphics card and 16 GB RAM. Tried dual booting Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Winddows 11 at home. During the installation stage, it asked for the Wifi password so that 3rd party upgrades can be installed while installing Ubuntu. When I typed the Wifi password it rejected it continously, inspite of it being the SAME password that is being used in Windows 11 and Internet works fine there. And the password doesn't contain any nonstandard keys (all alphanumeric and characters that is found on a standard English Keyboard).
I then tried to install Ubuntu using Wifi at Office. And there it worked. After installation its able to install upgrades, browse the internet etc using Office Wifi. But when I came home and tried to connect to Internet in Ubuntu using home Wifi, it refuses to connect to home Wifi as described above, repeatedly asking for password and rejecting the correct password. It only works if I setup my Mobile Hotspot and use that to connect to laptop.
Also everytime I have noticed that when connected Office Wifi when I restart from Ubuntu back to Windows 11, the System Time is in a different time (5 hours 30 min) behind. And am forced to go to Adjust Date/Time--> Sync Now. Why should 2 Operating Systems dual booted on the same laptop run with different times? Doesn't make sense.

My Ubuntu installation is practically useless without Internet access. And I can't bring my Personal Laptop to Office everytime. I have never faced such a weird situation. Never faced such a buggy Ubuntu before.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Search for the fix for time, it is something about Windows expecting the BIOS time to be local and Linux expects UTC or similar. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and post results for the wireless script so we might have an idea what the wifi issue is caused by

Comment: @Jeremy31 : I tried with a Wifi which works, here is the output of the Wireless Diagnostics https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/8mVC2P57cN/
And here's the Output of Wireless Diagnostics when unable to connect to home Wifi network inspite of typing correct password https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/FMKvjcZHdw/

Comment: Can you access the home router encryption settings and set it to WPA2 AES/CCMP only

Comment: I had to shift my house. And had to purchase a new Internet connection with a router. With this, Internet works absolutely fine. Thanks !!